# Emulator not running and showing a white screen

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

When I want to run the Android emulator or run the project, it gives me a white screen on the emulator.
[raster image of a vertical white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq2HI.png)

Do you have a solution for this problem?

I made various emulators, but when I run it, it gives me a white screen, but when I run it on the browser, it starts correctly.

Comment: Add your project code it's problem with your code.